# With start_time and end_time in Django models, how to print a series of times in an html page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

My model is:

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    (0, 'Monday'),
    (1, 'Tuesday'),
    (2, 'Wednesday'),
    (3, 'Thursday'),
    (4, 'Friday'),
    (5, 'Saturday'),
    (6, 'Sunday'),
)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)
```

One instance would be like: Sally 17:00 18:00 0

I want to output an HTML page using `start_time` and `end_time` in an 15-minute interval, something like this:

```
Sally
17:00
17:15
17:30
17:45
18:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define function `minutes_slices()` to prepare list of time you need, and then use it from `Teacher` instance like `Teacher.objects.get(pk=1).minutes_slices()`

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)

    def minutes_slices(self, minutes=15):
        # We can't add minutes to datetime.time, so we need to convert it to datetime
        start_date_time = datetime.combine(date.today(), self.start_time)
        end_date_time = datetime.combine(date.today(), self.end_time)
        next_time = start_date_time
        minutes_slices = [next_time.time()]
        if start_date_time < end_date_time:
            while next_time < end_date_time:
                next_time += timedelta(minutes=minutes)
                minutes_slices.append(next_time.time())
        return minutes_slices
```

`.strftime("%H:%M")` can be added to time() if formatting needed.

Comment: Nice. Probably it would be better to return `datetime` objects and leave the formatting concerns ("%H:%M")  for the template.

Comment: Agree, good point.

Comment: @weAreStarsDust Thank you so much!! Working perfectly. But it's start_time and end_time instead of start_date and end_date haha :-))

Comment: @weAreStarsDust BTW can i use a comparison between slice from `for slice in minutes_slices()` and models.TimeField? I tried to write a condition, but it seems not working

Comment: You can compare if you put `next_time.time()` in a `minutes_slices` list rather than `next_time.time().strftime("%H:%M")`